# In C, what does double asterisk ** in parameters of a function do

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, function-declaration

I came across a code snippet in linked list but this is the first time I see "**" double asterisk used in parameters. What does it do?

```
// Adding an item to the beginning of the list
void push(node_t ** head, int val) {
    node_t * new_node;
    new_node = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

Comment: **Read some good C programming book.** See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Your code is wrong, since `malloc` can fail. Provide some [mre] in your question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You mean `malloc` can fail because I didn't check if malloc returns NULL?

Comment: Yes, and we also don't know how you are using `push`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a variable like for example

```
int x = 10;
```

and want to change it in a function you need to pass it to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing a variable indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer within the function you have a direct access to the original variable and can change it.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *px )
{
    *px = 20;
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;

    printf( "Before calling f x = %d\n", x );

    f( &x );

    printf( "After  calling f x = %d\n", x );
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling f x = 10
After  calling f x = 20
```

If a variable has a pointer type like for example

```
node_t *head = NULL;
```

then again if you are going to change its value in a function you need to pass it to the function by reference as for example

```
push( &head, 10 );
```

So the corresponding function parameter will be declared like

```
void push(node_t ** head, int val);
```

And dereferencing the pointer to the original pointer `head` like

```
*head = new_node;
```

you can change the original pointer `head` defined in main.

If you will not pass the pointer by reference but pass it by value then the function will deal with a copy of the value of the original pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

Consider the preceding demonstration program where the original variable is passed to the function by value

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    x = 20;
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;

    printf( "Before calling f x = %d\n", x );

    f( x );

    printf( "After  calling f x = %d\n", x );
}
```

In this case the original variable x will not be changed. It is a copy of its value that was changed within the function. So the program output will be

```
Before calling f x = 10
After  calling f x = 10
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it declares a pointer to a `node_t` pointer, which is a function parameter.

Here is a simple example using character pointers:

```
char *charPointer = "This is a text.";
char **pointerToCharPointer = &charPointer;

printf("%s\n", charPointer);
(*pointerToCharPointer) = "This is something new.";
printf("%s\n", charPointer);
```

**Output:**

```
This is a text.
This is something new.
```

Comment: So if we translate this to English, Can we say line2 means `It's pointing to a pointer that points to a string "This is a text"`?

Comment: @gigaSecure Yes, it is a pointer to a string (char array). It is very well described here if you want to learn more about this:  
https://www.scaler.com/topics/c/string-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it’s because the function is updating the pointer value.

Remember that for a function to update a parameter, we must pass a pointer to that parameter:

```
void update( T *ptr ) // for any non-array object type T
{
  *ptr = new_T_value(); // writes a new value to the
}                       // thing ptr points to

int main( void )
{
  T var;
  update( &var );  // writes a new value to var
}
```

Now, let’s replace `T` with the pointer type `P *`:

```
void update( P **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_Pstar_value();
}

int main( void )
{
  P *var;
  update( &var );
}
```

The behavior is exactly the same - we’re updating the value of `var` through the expression `*ptr`, all that’s changed are the types.